# java.net.UnknownHostException: ..__MSBROWSE__ when using jcifs

Tags: java, smb, unknown-host

I'm trying to copy a file from a local directory to a network share on a windows box. I'm using jcifs 1.3.17. I successfully get a connection to the destination, actually create the file there, get a "canWrite" status of "true", but when I try to copy the contents of the local file to the remote file, I get the following error:

```
jcifs.smb.SmbException: Failed to connect to server
java.net.UnknownHostException: ..__MSBROWSE__.<01>
   at jcifs.netbios.NbtAddress.doNameQuery(NbtAddress.java:317)
```

.
.
.

code snippet:

```
        SmbFile source = new SmbFile(original);
        SmbFile dest = new SmbFile (target,auth);
        dest.createNewFile();
        boolean canWrite = dest.canWrite();
        source.copyTo(dest);
```

I don't get it... if I can create the file on the destination and smb sees that I can write to it, why does the **doCopy** fail?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't get it too **but...** try this. It works!

```
    String source = "smb://SERVER/PATH/FILE";
    NtlmPasswordAuthentication auth = new NtlmPasswordAuthentication(null, "USERNAME", "PASSWORD");
    SmbFile sourceFile = new SmbFile(source, auth);
    String destination = "LOCAL_PATH_TO_FILE";

    byte[] buffer;
    int length;

    try {
        FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(destination);
        InputStream fileInputStream = sourceFile.getInputStream();
        try {
            buffer = new byte[16 * 1024 * 1024];
            while ((length = fileInputStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                fileOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, length);
            }
        } finally {
            fileInputStream.close();
            fileOutputStream.close();
        }
    } catch (SmbException e) {
        // Error handling.    
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // Error handling.
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // Error handling.
    }
```

Credits go to this question and answer: [How to copy file from smb share to local drive using jcifs in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13359164/how-to-copy-file-from-smb-share-to-local-drive-using-jcifs-in-java)

Comment: I would replace try-finally with try with resource.

Comment: @rkosegi You are right. Use try-with-resource when you are using Java 1.7. My solution is for 1.6.