# How to copy files from Samba share to local using java

Tags: java, samba

I want to copy files from Samba share to local(c: drive). I am using java as a programming language.

Comment: You've asked 9 questions here. You should probably know by now to at least include your own attempt.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to copy file from smb share to local drive using jcifs in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13359164/how-to-copy-file-from-smb-share-to-local-drive-using-jcifs-in-java)